# why when I create a menu, it says "Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.newMenu() from this context. "

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I deployed a web app, which could call the function to create a new menu when the spreadsheet is open.
Below is the part I write

```
function onOpen(){
  var url = "https://script.google.com/a/slt.org.au/macros/s/AKfycby2pFGHc3qWaxnD4WGTLMEAPMUocohzH_-OsUPxwqi8kmWfRZs8/exec";
  var currentSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  var requestAction = "onOpen";
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+"?requestAction="+requestAction);
}
```

and in my web app, I write

```
function onOpen(currentSpreadsheet) {
  //Adds custom menu
SpreadsheetApp.openById(currentSpreadsheet);
  var menu = [{name: "Add row", functionName: "addRow"},
             {name: "Generate Invoice", functionName: "generateInvoice"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
}
```

I have a test and i am sure that the spreadsheet id has be transferred into the function, but it gives me an error of "Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.newMenu() from this context. "

I also tried

```
function onOpen(currentSpreadsheet) {
      //Adds custom menu
      var menu = [{name: "Add row", functionName: "addRow"},
                 {name: "Generate Invoice", functionName: "generateInvoice"}];
      SpreadsheetApp.openById(currentSpreadsheet).addMenu("Custom", menu);
    }
```

still not working. So is that means addMenu could only be used in a standalone or build-in script? but not in a google web app?

All the errors occurs when I try to use addMenu().

Comment: The error message is clear, addmenu only makes sense in a spreadsheet bound script, not in a standalone web app. Why are you trying this setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is running in context of a web app, but the `onOpen()` trigger runs only in a script bound to a Docs/Sheet/Form file.  In short, you can't pass nor install an `onOpen()` function into a spreadsheet from a web app.

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/):

> To use a simple trigger, simply create a function that uses one of
>   these reserved function names:
>
> `onOpen(e)` runs when a user opens a spreadsheet, document, or form
>   that he or she has permission to edit. ...